# Spring MVC requestParam value "&party" converts to "∂y"

Tags: java, spring-mvc, utf-8, html-entities, url-encoding

I am facing an issue with character encoding on request submission. The value "fred&party" is retrieved using @RequestParam (Spring MVC annotation). But the value which is returned converts to "fred∂y". Following were my observations from analysis:

1. According to [HTML Symbols](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_symbols.asp) the value *&part* corresponds to "∂" symbol (partial differential).
2. In one of the initially invoked Filters, the value can be seen as "fred%26party" which means the value was correctly encoded. But then weirdly, it changes to "fred∂y" when it reaches the formBacking method.
3. CharacterEncodingFilter is present in web.xml with *forceEncoding* param set to UTF-8 and even tomcat connector has *URIEncoding="UTF-8"* configured.

I was unable to find any solution to get this resolved. Not very sure why is this happening.

Comment: I may be mistaken but is that not what is expected by setting the encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: What is the encoding set at the request generating page (html/jsp)? Usually with such words, leave a space will resolve the issue, ie "fred & party" or you can encode the & as &amp

Comment: Which version of spring you are using? Tested it with spring 3.1.1 and it works well - receiving fred&party as expected

Comment: Hi Jay, i am using Spring 3.0.7 Release version. Are you passing the param through the url?

Comment: Hi Sridhar, the encoding set at jsp is also UTF-8.

Comment: If you want it as parameter - you should encode the string first.

Comment: I passed it as post request. are you using get?

Comment: Ok I used request method as GET and using cURL I pass url parame as `http://localhost:8082/test/abc.jdo?myvar=fred%26party` and I get `fred&party` in my controller method. Still this is with 3.1.1. May be you can try to invoke it with cURL and see what you get, so at least this will tell you if its related to your JSP encoding

Comment: Hi Jay, sorry for the delay. Did try to cURL in the url and i still get fred∂y in my controller. Do you have CharacterEncodingFilter configured in web.xml and URIEncoding="UTF-8" in tomcat's connector?